# Adding Multiple Image Slideshows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this worksheet to complete and one of the questions is to explain this code and to add one more image slideshow.

I don't really understand the javascript code and a bit confused as to how to add another image slideshow.

I understand the HTML and css but the javascript is confusing.
Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var slideIndex = [1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides1, .mySlides2 {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Multiple Slideshows</h2>

<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/sails.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: As it is, it is not even creating 1 slide show... please create a [mcve], or tell the person who asked you to make another slideshow that their slide show doesn't work in the first place lol

Comment: @TJ it should be working now and displaying images

Comment: Both your slide shows are now working (You made it work by calling the `showSlides()` method with right arguments. Are you still expecting an answer for this question? Which part of the JS you need explanation for?

Comment: Code is not a dynamic one.. You requirements needs changes in both html and JavaScript. Like create mySlides3 div similar to mySlides1  and mySlides2 and update the slideId array with new value "mySlides3"

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the code using an IDE to be human readable.
I believe it is pretty straight forward now. If you don't understand specific parts you can ask me in comments. (This not quality code, I believe it's a learning exercise so I kept it as it is)

```js
var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1];
var slideContainerSelectors = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]

function showSlides(nextslideIndex, slideContainerIndex) {
  var i;
  var slideContainerElement = document.getElementsByClassName(slideContainerSelectors[slideContainerIndex]);
  if (nextslideIndex > slideContainerElement.length) {
    slideIndex[slideContainerIndex] = 1
  }
  if (nextslideIndex < 1) {
    slideIndex[slideContainerIndex] = slideContainerElement.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slideContainerElement.length; i++) {
    slideContainerElement[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideContainerElement[slideIndex[slideContainerIndex] - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function plusSlides(increment, index) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[index] += increment, index);
  //----------------------------^ slideIndex[index] = slideIndex[index] + increment
}

showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.mySlides1,
.mySlides2 {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a grey background color */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Multiple Slideshows</h2>

<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/sails.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 3:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, the javascript makes more sense

Comment: but how do i add another image slideshow because I tried adding "mySlides3" (same HTML methods as the other two) to the "slideContainerSelectors" but it doesn't create a new slideshow

Comment: I added a 3rd one in the answer, you have to add the HTML, update both arrays  and initialize the slider `showSlides(1, 2);`

Comment: ah okay i see what i did wrong, i forgot to add that extra showSlides() line. Thank you very much